# Related Product Rules not showing up in magento2?

Tags: magento2, promotions, related-products, rules

I am trying to create Related product rules by following below link.

https://www.bluefishgroup.com/insights/ecommerce/related-products-rules-in-magento-2/

When i navigate into Marketing i can see only Catalog price rules and cart price rules under Promotion. Why Related product price rule not showing up?

My magento version is 2.2.4.

Please anyone advise on this. Any other settings are required to be done?

Comment: please go through https://docs.magento.com/m2/2.0/ee/user_guide/marketing/product-related-rule-create.html

Comment: I am not finding link inside Promotion like Related product Rule. Is it showing for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The related product rule feature is only available in Magento Commerce edition (previously known as Enterprise Edition).

If you can't see the link to it in your admin, then either the module has been disabled or you are not running Magento Commerce edition.

Also, that link is quite old (from 2016) and the screenshots in it reference Magento 2.0.x, which is not supported anymore. Here is the link to the 'Related Product Rules' section of the latest version of the Magento User Guide:

https://docs.magento.com/m2/ee/user_guide/marketing/product-related-rules.html

Comment: Yes , we are running community edition. is it possible to enable the module? Is it available on community edition?

Comment: The module is not available in Open Source Edition (previously known as Community Edition). The only way to get it is to either install a third-party extension which offers similar features (look on the Magento Marketplace) or upgrade to Commerce Edition (a little extreme, just for one module).